# Test the Regex OnBlur in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex

I have a textbox and I want to check if it contains only numbers (with no space and Special Character) onblur I don;t know how to check the Regex alert should Comes if Regex fails

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" placeholder="Contract ID" onblur="checkValue(this.value)">

//JS CODE
function checkValue(this) {
   //regex    ^[0-9+]*$
}
```

Comment: Also see [check if string contains only numbers, else show message](//stackoverflow.com/q/10380937) and [Check if a textbox contains numbers only](//stackoverflow.com/q/30323610)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use NaN?

```
 //JS CODE
function checkValue(x) {
   return isNaN(x);
}
```

This will return true if the value is not a number, else false if its not.

Comment: It's a good solution for checking numbers. But I think OP doesn't want dot `.` to be allowed. for Eg, `2.99` is not a `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" 
placeholder="Contract ID"> //Here you don't need any event as jquery automatically calls respective function when blur event occurs.


$("#txtFromDate").blur(function(){
   var reg = /^[0-9+]*$/;
   if (reg.test($("#txtFromDate").val())) {
      alert("Your number is valid.");
   }
   else{
      alert("Your number is not valid.");
   }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `test` to check regex against the input,

```js
function checkValue(val){
  if(!val || /^\d+$/.test(val) === false){
   alert('Failed')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="checkValue(this.value)" />
```

If you want user are allowed to type only numeric data then refer this post,
[HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Comment: regex fails when the Textbox empty which i don't want

Comment: @AkhilJain Updated the code and now check